# Connecting to URL with Token within SSIS

Tags: ssis, odata

I have been provided a URL such as this one (I've changed some elements for privacy):

https://api.encompass8.com/api?APIToken=xxxxxxx&APICommand=XYZ_SolverFullAccountString&EncompassID=XYZ

The API Token was masked. If you enter the URL in a browser, you get a download option. The data is stored in AWS.

Is there a connector in SSIS that can work with this? Thank you.

I have tried the XML Source and OData Source options but, if one of them works, don't know what to enter.

Here's what I got using the OData Source:

[image: OData Source Editor]